# Debugging Java - lines versus steps

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

**The Setup**

I normally use Eclipse for Java development.  When debugging, I use `F5` for "step into", and `F6` for "step over".  When I debug this code:

```
String var1 = " easy as ";
String str = new StringBuilder("abc").append(var1).append("123").toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

I press `F6` once per line (3 times).

When I debug the same code formatted like this:

```
String var1 = " easy as ";
String str = new StringBuilder("abc").append(var1)
                                     .append("123")
                                     .toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

I still press `F6` once per line (5 times).  Nothing strange or confusing going on.  Yet I still have a

**Question**

Is it possible, through compiler settings, debugger settings, or other mechanism, to make the first snippet debug like the second?

That is, in the first snippet, I want to have to press `F6`three times on line 2 before the debug pointer advances to line 3.

*Edit:*
I probably want to have to press `F6` **four** times on line 2, since that line of code contains four method calls.

**Edit 2**

Assuming this isn't possible, what I'd like is an ELI5 sort of explanation of what about the `bytecode -> debugger -> debug metadata` interaction makes it impossible.

Comment: The lines aren't where the debugger stops, it's the method call. So, are you wanting the compiler to remove line breaks?

Comment: No, but you can "step into" and then "step out"...

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for many years, and I don't know of any setting like the one you're looking for.

Comment: @DM I can, but that's exactly the kind of tedious button pressing I'm hoping to reduce.